# Is there a performance penalty for having tables in two databases

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a performance penalty for querying tables that are in two databases (which is asking if having tables in the same databse improve performance?)

Comment: @Naveen: I expect it has already been mentioned to you, but in case it has not: adding quote devices to questions is only appropriate if they highlight a quotation i.e. something from a manual or said by someone else. They are inappropriate as a general highlighting device.

Answer (score 2):

If the two databases are on the same server, no, there is no significant penalty. There might be a tiny penalty at the time of statement parsing and access-privilege checking. But it's tiny.

Comment: But to be cystal clear to the OP, if the two datbases are on different servers, there is usually a noticable penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Databases love tables - see third normal form.

That is what they love to eat

Comment: There is no problem - that is what databases do

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, performance impact should be negligible.

Since we are discussing about performance, ensure your databases are maintained well especially if it's a large database, make sure you have index maintenance/rebuild jobs, purging of unnecessary table data and other good practices going on in a periodic manner.